# **Plugging in Custom Serializer in Apache Ignite**

Tags: ignite

**Plugging in Custom Serializer in Apache Ignite**

I tried to add Kyro Serializer in the Binary Configuration bean  but at runtime it gave  me a class type conversion error.

My Code is

```
 <property name="binaryConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration">
                <property name="typeConfigurations">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryTypeConfiguration">
                            <property name="typeName" value="testPojo" />
                            <property name="serializer">
                                <bean class="com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers" />
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

Error Log is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers] to required type [org.apache.ignite.binary.BinarySerializer] for property 'serializer': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:576)
    ... 104 more
```

On digging in the Apache Ignite provided BinarySerializer, came to a conclusion that one has to write a custom implementation for the serializer as Other plugin Serializers to implement it.

How is the Optimized Marshaller beneficial ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BinarySerializer` is an interface that can be implemented to customize (de)serialization logic for a particular type. This is an analogy to `Externalizable` for `BinaryMarshaller`, which is the default marshaller since Ignite 1.5. Refer to this page for details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller

`OptimizedMarshaller` implements legacy serialization protocol, which was used before binary format was introduced. It's still available, but binary format is recommended.

You can also implement your own marshaller (e.g., based on Kryo). To do this, implement the `Marshaller` interface and provide this implementation in configuration via `IgniteConfiguration.setMarshaller()` property.

Comment: Is it neccessary to use a Custom Serializer Like kryo to get space and speed optimization or the Binary marshaller is good enough on its own ?

Comment: Binary marshaller is much more compact and efficient than Kryo or native Java serialization